# Why does switching to a different search result take less time?

Tags: google-chrome, search, hyperlink, delay

Often when I'm searching the web using Google (on Google Chrome) I'll click on a link but then change my mind and click on a different link while the first link is still loading. Doing this seems to take no longer than just clicking the second link to start with.

Why is this the case? Is it because Chrome has code that delays sending requests to Google's servers? Is it because there is a warm up period in which data unrelated to the website I selected needs to go back and forth?

Also, clicking on links in Google Chrome seems to take much longer than using `wget`. Is this related?